# Pipe not working correctly

Tags: c++, unix, pipe

My goal is to get the output of the first command and use it as the input for the second command, but the problem is that it is only going through my parent condition, (pid > 0), and never the child. I have tried duping in the parent, but it didnt work. Any help will be appreciated! In case you were wondering, I am doing this in C:

```
int pipe_a1[2];
int pipe_a2[2];
command1 = {'ls','-a'}
command2 = {'cat','newFile'}

if (pipe(pipe_a1) < 0 || pipe(pipe_a2) < 0) {
    cout << "pipe failed." << endl;
    exit(1);
}
    pid = fork()
    if (pid == 0) {
      close(pipe_a1[1]);
      close(pipe_a2[0]);
      dup2(pipe_a1[0], STDIN_FILENO);
      dup2(pipe_a2[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
      execvp(command2[0],command2)

    } else if(pid > 0) {
      close(pipe_a1[0]);
      close(pipe_a2[1]); 
      execvp(command1[0],command1)
    } else {
      printf("Fork Failed");
    }
```

Comment: In your `if (pid > 0)` clause, you don't `dup2` any output stream. Could that be the problem?

Comment: @Ben thank you for the speedy response I appreciate it! Unfortunately that didnt work =/.  Also, I tried that earlier and it didnt seem to be the problem. It reads the command1 fine, but never reads command2.

Comment: This is rather C, isn't it?

Comment: @Zereges for instance, I were to run "ls | cat", it will print out the ls command fine, but never acknowledge the cat command.

Comment: @Tyler Try a different example. `ls | cat` simply pipes `ls` to the `cat` command which will just print out `ls` ...

Comment: @Ben for instance if I do this: who | ls , it'll print my computer name and console and the time. This isnt right.

Comment: In the child process, you `dup()`ed stdin and stdout. Why? In parent process you never `dup()`ed any. Let's say `ls` is running in child, would `ls` need any input? Where will `ls` send output`? How about the parent? Don't you want it to read the output of the child?

Comment: Are you a CSCI442 student?

Comment: @Tyler - you are using `|` incorrectly. `ls` doesn't read from `stdin`. You might want to try something like `ls | tail -1`.

Comment: @alvits but doesnt the parent just recieve the child output be the stdin for the parent process of whatever command is executed first, such as the ls, then it will be the stdout for the parent process? Also, the following command: ls | tail -1 , in my shell gives me the results of ls

Comment: @ocket8888 no why do you ask?

Comment: Because that's what the class is doing right now. It's not against the rules or anything, I just had a professor I could direct you to for help.

Comment: @Tyler - what are you expecting from `ls | tail -1`? Are you expecting the pipe `|` to print the output of 2 commands? `|` is a pipe and therefore one is a producer and the other a consumer.

Comment: @Tyler, if you just want both the parent and child to write on the standard output, you don't need pipe at all.

Comment: @alvits yes correct the ls is the producer and the tail is the consumer, but when I run that command in my shell it prints off the output of running ls by itself rather then the last instance of the current directory.

Comment: @Tyler - you are possibly running a broken shell. Use a standard shell and be amazed how it just works.

Comment: @alvits this is my own implementation of a shell that I cant seem to get working correctly.

Comment: @Tyler - Listen to advise and adjust your code accordingly. You need your child (producer) to close stdin and dup stdout to pipe and on parent (consumer) you need to dup(stdin).  This will allow the output of child get sent to parent via fd. If you still want to stand on ground by virtue that child and parent has read and write the same stdout and stdin, then you are on your own.

Comment: @alvits would I still need to make two pipe calls or just one?

Comment: Just one call. Because you only need 1 pair of fd. One endpoint is for the stdout of producer and the other endpoint is for the stdin of the consumer.